# Angular Js , Hide a button everytime a value increments

Tags: javascript, angularjs, button, increment

As you can see on the screenshot, the button is incremented every time an index is incremented.

What I want to know is that every time the index increment those preceding number will no longer have the button.

For example on the screenshot 1 and 2 has each button which is the Insert question below button. The button should only appear on the current highest number, on the screenshot button should only appear in number 2.

javascript

```
  me.create_question_object = function (index) {
  }
```

html

```
<div class="col-md-12 yq-default-pad  top50 text-center">
   <div class="text-center">
      {$ $index + 1 $}.)
      <button  ng-hide ng-click="main.create_question_object($index)" class="btn btn-success">
         <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Insert Question Below</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI1R0.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you have an `ng-repeat` on the questions, therefore you have some kind of an array that holds the questions.

If so, you can show the button on the last question with a `ng-if="$index === myArray.length-1"`.

$index is a special scope variable that angular adds to the scope of the `ng-repeate` directive.

```js
angular.module('myModule', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.questions = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  })


angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('root'), ['myModule']);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <ul ng-controller="ctrl">
    <li ng-repeat="item in questions">
      {{item}}
      <button ng-if="$index === questions.length-1">&times;</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```